# check a string exist in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node like this on Firebase database, it contains an array with 2 user.

[image: This is my node on Firebase]

Now when a other user login, how I can check if the uid of that user exist in this node yet?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store `uid` using shared preferences of the particular user in the app when the user is registering or what so ever is generating new `uid`. Then when user logs in just compare it with all the values of the user database (in which all users `uid` are saved).